undefined reference to the library
i don't know a lot about including custom libraries, i need some help in raylib
i recently installed it using msys2 because this shell automatically makes your raylib archives to be in the right place in the mingw folder, now VSC doesn't mark the include <raylib.h> as an error, the same with the functions in raylib.
now, when i want to run the code with a basic function like initwindow this message appears: undefined reference to `InitWindow'
when i asked about why this problem happens, in other forums they told me to solve the problems with the linker, but actually i have no idea about what the linker is...

but actually i have no idea about what the linker is Then you are attempting to use external libraries too soon.  Please note that VSCode does not help you in any way to link to a library. Either you have to edit your tasks.json and add the linker settings or use a Makefile or use CMake and the CMakeTools extension.

You probably need to first read this to understand how your compiler works and what a linker is for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work
